# Why can't my VPN Clients connect to addresses on a different subnet?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, subnet

So, I've just transitioned our network from a class C to a class A. At the moment, I've got the router configured to hand out DHCP from 10.0.0.101 to 200.

On our Windows 2008 domain server, I've configured the RRAS properties to hand VPN clients addresses from 10.0.250.1 to 10.0.250.254.

The server itself has two NICs, the internal ( 10.0.0.201 ) does not have a gateway. The external ( which clients connect over ) is public facing.

The problem I have is that clients connecting to the Windows VPN cannot communicate with devices inside the network. The prime example here is the domain server itself - which has internal DNS entries configured - that cannot be pinged by VPN clients by its DNS name or internal IP.

I'm sure I'm missing an element here, because this doesn't seem like a very outlandish approach, but I'm definitely coming up short and I'm not seeing any configuration options that I haven't addressed already. Do I need to give the outfacing NIC an internal IP as well? Do I need to bridge the connections? What's the proper approach here?

This is why I try to stick to code. Thanks for anyone's help.

Comment: Classful addressing went out the door ~20 years ago. Can you please edit your question to include proper CIDR notation?

Comment: If I were a real network engineer and not a software engineer and I could do that without strain, yes. But does it change your ability to answer the question in any way? Or are you just being picky?

Comment: If you're going to be configuring networking devices, you might as well take an hour or so to learn about CIDR, as that is how all modern networks are documented, controlled, and organized. And yes, you'll generally get better answers by providing detailed information in a format that people are expecting to see it in. Classful notation is a relic, that is not able to communicate information clearly in today's world. Did you mean that you moved from a `/24` network to a `/8` network?

Comment: Yes, but I feel like it has little bearing on addressing the problem.

Comment: It's hard to understand your issue but if you clients connect to the external facing NIC and the VPN server's internal facing NIC is what passes the traffic, if it doesn't have a gateway I would think it wouldn't route the info correctly.  Maybe try putting the gateway in?